# Oracle subquery refactoring how to return filtered rows and all their ancestors

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using a table to modeling multi-level menu in a application:

```
CREATE TABLE
    CWE_MENUS
    (
        NODE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PARENT_NODE INTEGER,
        INLINE_SORT_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
        ICON VARCHAR2(32),
        TEXT VARCHAR2(32) NOT NULL,
        ACTION_TYPE VARCHAR2(32),
        ACTION_INFO VARCHAR2(512),
        ENABLED CHAR(1),
        REMARK VARCHAR2(128),
        PRIMARY KEY (NODE_ID),
        CONSTRAINT CWE_MENUS_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (PARENT_NODE) REFERENCES "CWE_MENUS" ("NODE_ID")
    );
```

And I using such SQL to fetch all menu data:

```
select  T.*, case when exists(select node_id from cwe_menus D where D.parent_node=T.node_id) then 0 else 1 end as leaf from (
    WITH link(NODE_ID, PARENT_NODE, INLINE_SORT_NO, ICON, TEXT, ACTION_TYPE, ACTION_INFO, ENABLED,  REMARK, lvl,pth) AS (
        SELECT NODE_ID, PARENT_NODE, INLINE_SORT_NO, ICON, TEXT, ACTION_TYPE, ACTION_INFO, ENABLED, REMARK, 1 as lvl, ''||node_id as pth
        FROM cwe_menus
        where parent_node is null
        UNION ALL
        SELECT p2.NODE_ID, p2.PARENT_NODE, p2.INLINE_SORT_NO, p2.ICON, p2.TEXT, p2.ACTION_TYPE, p2.ACTION_INFO, p2.ENABLED,  p2.REMARK, p1.lvl + 1 as lvl, p1.pth||'.'||p2.node_id as pth
        FROM link p1 INNER JOIN cwe_menus p2 ON p1.node_id = p2.parent_node
    )
    SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY INLINE_SORT_NO SET order1
    SELECT distinct * FROM link ORDER BY order1
) T
```

This works like a magic, but how can I apply some conditions to filter data while keep the tree structure ? I mean return all matched rows and their ancestor rows. I also need all siblings sorted by INLINE_SORT_NO, I also need `LVL, PATH, LEAF` columns.

I have checked oracle documentation and some tutorial on internet, but none of them have mentioned how to do this, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [hierarchical queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) -

```
SELECT v.*, connect_by_isleaf as LEAF, level as LVL, sys_connect_by_path(text,'.') as PATH
FROM 
    (
      SELECT s.*
        FROM cwe_menus s
     CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_node = node_id
       START WITH (text = 3) /* filter condition*/
    ) v
CONNECT BY PRIOR node_id = parent_node
START WITH parent_node IS NULL
ORDER SIBLINGS BY inline_sort_no
```